# mongodb query by reference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following database in mongodb:

```
{"Team":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"},"TeamName":"NA"}}
{"Card":{"_id":{"$oid":"5a46626e150ed3f847f01bac"},"Number":1,"Page":1,"Team":[{"$oid":"5a465ca9150ed3f847f01b92"}]}}
```

It has a Card which has id of a team, and I'm trying to make a query to get the team of a specific Card. I tried:

```
Team = db.test.findOne({"Card.Number":1})
Team_data = db.test.find({_id:{$in:team.Team}}).toArray()
```

However it is giving me a error in the second line:

```
2018-01-02T15:22:21.112+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$in needs an array",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:717:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:117:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:288:5
DBQuery.prototype.toArray@src/mongo/shell/query.js:337:12
@(shell):1:13
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Try `team = db.test.findOne({"Card.Number":1})
    Team_data = db.test.find({_id:{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray()`

Comment: That way it does't give me a error, but the result was not the expected. The output was [ ].
How can it show me the team informations?

Comment: Sorry you need `Team_data = db.test.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few things incorrect here.

1. You are referencing the incorrect field reference in `$in` operator. Should be `{$in:team.Card.Team}`
2. You've incorrect field name for comparison. Should be `Team._id`

Complete code

```
team = db.test.findOne({"Card.Number":1}) 
Team_data = db.test.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray()
```

You can also do the whole [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in one query.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"Card.Number":1}},
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "test",
      "localField": "Card.Team",
      "foreignField": "Team._id",
      "as": "team_data"
    }
 },
 { "$project": {"team_data":1} }
])
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly!

Comment: I have a new problem, I have now more documents of type Card and Team, so I divided them in two diferent collections: cards1617 and teams1617. Now I want to print the teams for each card, so I tryied:     `var team = db.cards1617.find()`     and       `while(team.hasNext()){team_data = db.teams1617.find({"Team._id":{$in:team.Card.Team}}).toArray‌​()}`   but now it gives me       `2018-01-02T17:38:56.142+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: team.Card is undefined :
@(shell):1:71`      , how can I solve this to print the team os each card in my collection?

Comment: Try `var card=db.cards1617.find() and while(card.hasNext()){team_data = db.teams1617.find({"_id":{$in:card.Team}}).toArray‌​‌​()}` Btw `$lookup` is a also an option.

Comment: that way it gives me an error `2018-01-02T17:57:17.825+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$in needs an array",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCommandCursor@src/mongo/shell/query.js:717:1
DBQuery.prototype._exec@src/mongo/shell/query.js:117:28
DBQuery.prototype.hasNext@src/mongo/shell/query.js:288:5
DBQuery.prototype.toArray@src/mongo/shell/query.js:337:12
@(shell):1:35`

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your new document structure. Please verify the document structure you've and map the fields appropriately. Try all the possible things and if you still cant resolve please consider creating a new question. So this way we can keep issues separately.